# Getting bytes from InputStream to fixed length message

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, bufferedinputstream

I read a lot methods and my head now is kind of overflow with different methods and i can't do what i want. From arduino i am sending fixed 8 byte message. Due to baud rate, HW problems or what ever i get the message separated in random sizes (for example : 1st msg = 1byte, 2nd msg = 7 bytes). To fix this have to add bytes from buffer to new array with a sequence. To test if message is correct i will check with CRC32. I want to do testing program to get 8 byte message, calculate CRC and send it back to arduino to check if it was correct. In this case i will get Rx/Tx checking.

If buffer size is `buffer[256]`, how to get how may bytes i received, add them to `byte[] c = new byte[8]` and ten calculate CRC32.

`buffer.length` gives always 256.

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    int destination = 0;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream

        /* Should i add to c array??? */
        byte[] c      = new byte[8];    // Fixed length message array

        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream

                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                // Here i should add buffer array to my array
                //System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, c, destination, buffer.length);
                //destination = ??? // number of bytes added to c and then do some if c is full calculate crc
                CRC32 checksum = new CRC32();
                checksum.update(c, 0, c.length);
                long checksumValue = checksum.getValue();
                System.out.println("CRC: " + checksumValue);
                write(""+checksumValue);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Sent: " + message + "...");
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");     
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) buffer.length gives you always 256, because you are allocating 256 in the following line :

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
```

2) `mmInStream.read(buffer)` returns the number of bytes read or -1 if you have reached the end of the stream

3) Let's say you read 8 bytes from the stream. That means that you're buffer will have your 8 bytes that you just read and the remaining 248 as 0's (since the buffer is 256). So depending on you're data protocol you will have to take this in consideration. Most cases, you will have a termination byte (or several) pattern. Which will let you know that you got a complete message.

Let's say your termination pattern would be a 0 byte, then it would look something like this :

```
if (nrBytes <= BUFFER_SIZE) { // if buffer is enough
    for (int i = 0; i < nrBytes; i++) {
        //append byte to your byte[] c array 
        // or whatever data structure is suppose to hold each message
        if (0 == buffer[i]) {
              // termination pattern = complete message! 
              // CRC check
              // Do work with your message!
        }
    }
    buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; //reset buffer (resets all to 0's)
}
```